# Is it possible to include a equation in my own bibtex files??

Tags: bibtex, matrices

Is it possible to include a equation in my own bibtex files?? I create a bibtex file in which I expect some matrix could be contained. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you make your question a bit more specific? What do you mean by "bibtex file" precisely? Is it your bibliography file, which ends with `.bib`? It would be great if you could supply with an MWEB, i.e. a short compilable document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, shows what you have tried and a file containing a small bibliography (if this is relevant to your question).

Comment: Thanks a lot , @marmot.      The file is created as this, and I would cite it as a reference in the paper, but the output says it does not match its definition.        @Article{Note1,
  journal       = {The origin is due to the matrix \\begin{align} \begin{pmatrix}a_{C\beta}^{(+)}\\ a_{C\beta}^{(-)} \end{pmatrix} \end{align} },
}

Comment: If you do not use `align` but `@article{Note1, journal = {The origin is due to the matrix {$\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}a_{C\beta}^{(+)}\\ a_{C\beta}^{(-)} \end{pmatrix}$ }, } `, I *think* it will work. Of course, I do not know how you use this precisely, so I can only guess.

Comment: it is not an error to bibtex or latex but surely that is not the title of a journal?

Comment: did you try? What error did you get? You should add the test document and the full error message to your question so people can debug it.

Comment: @David, sorry to delay to reply. Actually I want to use this kind of 'Reference' to write a note about some thing. I tried about the solutions of marmot, it still fails as long as you contain something like \begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}

Comment: "it still fails" does not allow anyone to guess what you did. If you get an error message you should put the full error message in the question and also a complete small document that reproduces the error, so people can debug. However bibtex does not care what tex markup is in the fields and latex will not give an error for `\begin{pmatrix}` so long as you are in math mode and have defined that environment eg with the `amsmath` package. However although I would expect no tex error it is completely a mis-use of bibtex!! `journal=` should be the name of a journal like `Annals of Mathematics`

Comment: journal={can contain any simple mathematical formula as long as you use $this form$ in my experience}, not just the name of some journals, as you said.

Comment: @FrankLi `journal=` is the bibtex field for the name of the journal, of course you do not get an error from bibtex if you put `journal="apple"` or `journal="$e=mc^2$` but it makes no sense, why misuse bibtex in that way?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question in the title is yes, you can include more or less arbitrary latex markup in a bibtex file. bibtex doesn't process it as latex, it just copies the strings to the `.bbl` file that it generates.  The example alignment provided by the OP in the comment below the question works without error in latex (although with some warnings about missing fields from bibtex)

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

zzzzz \cite{Note1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{dontdothis}

\end{document}
```

with the `dontdothis.bib` file

```
 @Article{Note1,
 journal = {The origin is due to the matrix
 \begin{align} \begin{pmatrix}a_{C\beta}^{(+)}\\ a_{C\beta}^{(-)} \end{pmatrix} \end{align} }
 }
```

There may be reason to include a display math in a *title* but using a numbered enviornment such as `align` doesn't really make sense in a bibliography entry where the entries are going to be sorted by bibtex so numbering equations is well defined but just confusing. However there can never be a good reason to put such an entry in a `journal` field, the only use for such a field is to enter the name of a journal.

Perhaps you are looking for the `endnotes` package rather than using bibtex? It is hard to guess the intent here.